# Modelo de Capas en VB.net

Tags: vb.net

Buenas espero que todos esten super bien.

Tengo una consulta es posible trabajar el modelo de capas en vb.net con un txt como base de datos ?
Actualmente tengo un proyecto pero la informacion esta en la clase en el windows form y se guarda bien en un txt , quiero pasar ese txt a otra clase que sea capa de datos pero no encuentro información para poder hacerlo.Si alguien tuviera un ejemplo le agradeceria la ayuda!

Gracias por su tiempo

Comment: De poder se puede, también puedes guardar como xml o JSON que en rigor son también texto plano. Lo que no entiendo de tu pregunta, es eso de pasar el txt a otra clase ahí me perdí completamente

Comment: Seria actualmente esta hecho en un windows form y todo esta en la clase que trae ese form entonces digamos que seria todo en una capa.
Lo que necesito serian 3 capas una con la fuente y los datos en una clase, otra con los metodos y calculos usando de referencia la capa de datos que seria en otra clase, y luego la tercera capa es la visual que es ingresar y ver los datos en el form en otra clase.
Gracias por responder y espero que me entiendas jaja